# c# if Scanner reading save to database -- form background--Motorola hand scanner

Tags: c#, database, barcode-scanner, motorola

I wrote a simple program for reading with hand scanner code 39 barcode(USB port) to textbox and save the result ('if textbox changed') to database. But if the form is hidden then it is not read to the correct place. Can someone help me to solve this problem? I think somehow if the scanner reading then save automatically to database but how?

some code:

```
     void countDown_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {

   TimeRemained--;

   if (TimeRemained == 0 && (txt_kod.Text != ""))
   {
       try
       {
           if (txt_kod.Text.Length == 4 )
           {

               connection.Open();
               OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
               command.Connection = connection;
               //MessageBox.Show(mini);
               command.CommandText = " insert into Jelenlet (Kod,Datum) values  ('" + txt_kod.Text + "','" + adat + "')";

               command.ExecuteNonQuery();
               // MessageBox.Show(txt_kod.Text);


               connection.Close();
               txt_kod.Text = String.Empty;

           }
           else
           {
               //MessageBox.Show("Rossz beolvasás");
               Console.Beep();
               Console.Beep();
               Console.Beep();

               txt_kod.Text = String.Empty;
               connection.Close();
           }
       }

       catch (Exception ex)
       {

           MessageBox.Show("Error " + ex);
           connection.Close();

       }





   }

      private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Now;
        this.time_lbl.Text = dateTime.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
    }
    Timer countDown = new Timer();
    int TimeRemained;
    string adat;
    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //timer2.Start();

        countDown.Interval = 1000;
        TimeRemained = 1;

        countDown.Tick += new EventHandler(countDown_Tick);
        countDown.Enabled = true;


      //  MessageBox.Show(idoszak_lbl.Text);
        //MessageBox.Show(adat);
        adat = time_lbl.Text + "." + idoszak_lbl.Text;
        //adat = time_lbl.Text + "." + idoszak_lbl.Text + "." + lbl_hobbi.Text; // csütörtök vizsgálat esetén













    }
```

I have lot of forms which is used in same time in this program and i wont wait for reading, i would like to automatize it.

I would like to use Motorola hand scanner.

Comment: Could you add some code to see what you already have.

Comment: Why are you reading it into the text box? Is user interaction required before saving it to the database?

Comment: Did you do any research? A scanner is a HID, it will write the scanned code into the currently active control simulating keypresses. If you want to read scanner input without a control having focus, you'll need to use the scanner's API.

Comment: Does `Form` `KeyDown` event intercept this? If yes, then you can use it.

Comment: Oguz Ozgu- i read to text box and with textbox changed event with a timer thick (after 1000 write it)  i write it with some xtra fields to database.